# Equipment required for AWS outpost

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, cisco

Have anybody configured network equipment for AWS outpost?
The demarcation point is the patch pannel in AWS rack. Requirment is to configure equipment back from the rack to internet. The rack will be put in DC. Based on documentation I found on internet - 6 Nexus switches are required. I think such configuration is overkill for us.

There will be not any additional devices connected in DC to the outpost (most likely) and we dont have AS, neither think to get one. Its just one rack so I dont think I need 6 Nexus switches with full fail-over capability on eatch layer.

I am thinking about 2 switches on access-layer, and colapse core connected to firewall. Not  sure what  equipment  I would need to achive that especially the BGP part. Cisco the best as I know it to some extend. Any ideas?

[Cisco Extends Enterprise-grade Datacenter Networking To AWS Outpost](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/solutions/collateral/data-center-virtualization/application-centric-infrastructure/solution-overview-c22-743174.html)

What other switches/eqipment could I use?

Answer (score 3):

If you’re getting an Outpost installed, which is not cheap, then *surely* you’ve got an *Enterprise Support contract*, right? Work with your TAM or with Outpost support to agree on the requirements.

I don’t see how a random answer on the internet could be any better than a word from the supplier of those tens of thousands dollars worth of equipment. ;)

Comment: Totally agree with you but unfortunatelly AWS doesnt care as much as you think. I am surprised myself. Basically "dermarcation point is rack patch pannel. Configure the network and let us know when is ready. As ref. check the documentation". I thought somebody had similar issue with Outpost but yeah - its expensive toy.

Comment: An outpost can be tens or hundreds of thousands of dollars. We've always found AWS support excellent, and if you have enterprise support and a TAM you should have top notch support.

Answer (score 2):

Only 2 "customer devices" are required, can be [Cisco](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/solutions/collateral/data-center-virtualization/application-centric-infrastructure/solution-overview-c22-743174.html), [Juniper](https://forums.juniper.net/t5/Enterprise-Cloud-and/AWS-Outposts-in-a-Juniper-QFX-Based-Datacenter/ba-p/470768), Arista, and any others which support both BGP and LACP, and support one of the supported fiber options documented at [Outpost Network Requirements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/outposts/latest/userguide/outposts-requirements.html#facility-networking). Ask your account SA to file a "SpecReq" for an Outpost Specialist SA to answer your Outpost Networking questions, or you can ask them to connect you with AWS Professional Services who can go deeper including getting as hands on as you want them to, including creating the switch and router configurations for you. (BTW, I'm the Global Lead in AWS ProServe for Outposts)

Comment: Good information from the source. I'm curious about the target market for AWS Outposts. Who are ideal organizations for the service?

Comment: The "Industry Examples" tab of https://aws.amazon.com/outposts/ is the official answer to ewwhite's question, and the "Common Use Cases" tab of that same URL is also worth reading.  The "Customer reference" section of that same page has specific customer examples.  I've seen enough customers with Data Residency use cases I co-presented https://pages.awscloud.com/Architecting-for-Data-Residency-on-AWS-Outposts_2021_0327-CMP_OD.html to spread this knowledge more widely.